# Installing JDK from self extracting bin on Cygwin

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, cygwin

I want to install the JDK in cygwin on my windows machine. I am downloading the linux version of JDK from oracle site using wget command. Here is the list of commands I am running to install JDK:

`wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u31-b04/jdk-6u31-linux-x64.rpm.bin`

`chmod a+x jdk-6u31-linux-x64.rpm.bin`

`./jdk-6u31-linux-x64.rpm.bin`

All these instructions are same as suggested by Oracle for installing JDK over [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-linux-64-rpm-138254.html) but I am getting the following errors:

[image]

Comment: Why on earth don't you use a native Windows JDK??

Comment: Because I am trying to configure hadoop on my development machine which is possible only for linux machine and in windows I am using cygwin to create linux like environment as suggested by Apache.

Comment: This will not work. Even Cygwin CAN NOT execute Linux binaries in Windows. Cygwin executables are also .EXE (COFF) files.

Comment: @Ivan- Apache recommends cygwin for Hadoop installation on windows. please see it [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, those messages indicate that what you are trying to execute is an HTML document!  In other words, the download has failed and given you an error page rather than an installer.

However, assuming that you succeed in downloading the (Linux) installer, it is unlikely that it will install properly, and there is about ZERO chance that the installed tools will run.  Applications that have been compiled for Linux don't run on Cygwin.

What you need to do is to download and install the JDK for Windows, and then tweak your cygwin profile a bit.  This page explains: http://horstmann.com/articles/cygwin-tips.html.

(If you Google for "java cygwin" there are various other tips for making Java work from Cygwin.  However, in my experience there are a few rough edges ... due to the fact that the Windows Java utilities *expect* to have been called with windows-style arguments, pathnames, classpaths, etcetera.)